A Travel Question from City A to City B
I know it is a basic question however, I cannot figure out the error in my attempt to solution.

Ronald, who is in Çorum, can reach Tokat either by using his own car,
a 450 km road or by taking a 270 km train journey. At 13:00, he
realizes that there are still two hours to depart on the train, so he
immediately sets off using the road with his car. Ronald reaches Tokat
at the same time by train. Since the average speed of Ronald's car and
the average speed of the train are the same, at what time did Ronald
arrive in Tokat?
A) 17:00 B) 18:00 C) 19:00 D) 20:00 E) 21:00

My dissection: 
Visual representation of travel from Çorum to Tokat
Since average speed of car and train are same, the proposition below is true:
$$\frac{450}{V} - \frac{270}{V} = 2  $$
$$\frac{180}{V} = 2  $$
$$ V = 90  $$
Since average speed is 90 km per hour, Train will reach Tokat  in
$$\frac{270}{90} = 3  $$
hours. 13:00 + 3 hours is 16:00 is not in the options. Where am I wrong? Thanks in advance.

If he realizes that there are still two hours at 13:00, then the departure time should be 15:00 and the answer is $B$.

I am not sure if I understand the question. What does "there are still two hours at 13:00" mean? that he starts driving at 11:00?

The question is orginally in Turkish and there is a translation problem. I am updating the question.

When you said “Ronald reaches Tokat at the same time by train”, does this mean that even though he departed $2$ hours earlier by car, he still reached Tokat at the same time as the train (which departed $2$ hours later than Ronald did)?

Yes, in other words, Ronald departs from Çorum by car at 13:00 and the train departs from Çorum at 15:00.

The speed of the car and train are equal and equal $90$.  So the car will take $\frac{450}{90}=5$ hours and will arrive at $13 + 5 = 18$.  Then Train will take $\frac{270}{90}=3$ hours and will arrive at $(13+2) + 3 = 18$.  Either way you do it they both arrive ate $18$.  But if you calculate the train you have to take into account the train isn't going to depart until "13:00 + 2 = 15:00$.

$\frac{450}{t}=\frac{270}{t-2}$

I wanted to post a more in-depth answer to this question. Here's the information we know:

The average speed $(s)$ of the car and train are the same.
By car, the travel distance is $450$ km, while the train journey distance is only $270$ km.
Ronald departs by car $2$ hours before the train departs.
He reaches Tokat at the same time as the train.

Based on the information, we can write distance equations for the car and the train. The average speed is $s$, and the travel time (in hours) is $t$.
$\underline{\text{Car distance:}}\;s\cdot t=450\\
\underline{\text{Train distance:}}\;s\cdot (t-2)=270$
This is a system of equations that we can use to solve for $s$ and $t$. We can start by solving the first equation for $s$, then substituting that value of $s$ into the second equation to solve for $t$.
$$s\cdot t=450\;\;\;\Rightarrow\;\;\;s=\frac{450}{t}\tag{1}$$
$$s\cdot(t-2)=270\;\;\;\Rightarrow\;\;\;\frac{450}{t}\cdot(t-2)=270\tag{2}$$
$$\frac{450}{t}\cdot(t-2)=270\;\;\;\Rightarrow\;\;\;450-\frac{900}{t}=270\;\;\;\Rightarrow\;\;\;-\frac{900}{t}=-180\;\;\;\Rightarrow\;\;\;\boxed{t=5}\tag{3}$$
The solution $t=5$ tells us that the trip by car took $5$ hours. So if Ronald departed at 13:00, he arrived at 18:00, which is choice B.

As Bowei Tang points out that, if he realizes that there are still two hours at 13:00, then the departure time should be 15:00 and the answer is B.
